# linq query gone bad

Tags: c#, linq

I have a really complicated linq query that I thought I finally got the syntax right for but it's throwing an exception at runtime: {"The method or operation is not implemented."}

Could someone *please* take a look?

Thanks!

```
var order = from Ord in imageCreatorDataContext.Orders
                            join Sub in imageCreatorDataContext.SubjectInfos on Ord.ID equals Sub.OrderID
                            join Pkg in imageCreatorDataContext.PackageOrders on new { Sub.OrderID, Sub.SubjectID } equals new { Pkg.OrderID, Pkg.SubjectID }
                            join Cpd in imageCreatorDataContext.CustomerPackageDescriptions on new { Pkg.OrderID, Pkg.Pkg } equals new { OrderID = Cpd.OrderID, Pkg = Cpd.ID }
                            where Ord.ReceiveDate != null && Cpd.Description.Contains("MPACD") && Sub.Usage != "unprint" && Ord.ID == _orderID && Sub.SubjectID == s.SubjectID
                            select new { border = Pkg.Theme, background = Pkg.Background };
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown and on what part?

Comment: Assuming from the name that the data type of `Ord.ReceiveDate` is `Nullable<DateTime>` (i.e. `datetime?`) you should use `!Ord.ReceiveDate.HasValue` rather than `Ord.ReceiveDate != null`...

Comment: Is this Linq to SQL or Entity Framework?  You also need to show us the line where this exception is *actually* occurring - Linq queryables don't execute immediately, so it's not going to be on this specific line, it's going to be sometime later.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that this is an exception you are throwing from one of your methods?

Example:

```
public void someMethod()
{
   throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one or more of the collections you're exposing through imageCreatorDataContext is not implemented, like Orders, SubjectInfos, PackageOrders, etc. Check everyo one of them and you should find at least one "Throw new NotImplementedException()" somewhere.